# Why do we need to run `io.run` in both main thread and a new thread `t` within asico tutorial Timer.5 example?

Tags: boost, boost-asio

Reference: [tuttimer5](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer5/src.html)

[coliru demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/50ef7044062f6d23)

Based on the tutorial, the main function looks like the following:

```
int main()
{
  boost::asio::io_context io;
  printer p(io);
  boost::thread t(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_context::run, &io));
  io.run(); // Why do we need to call io.run() here?
  t.join();

  return 0;
}
```

I want to understand why we need to have two `io.run();` in the main function.
Here is my test result:

**Test 1 (call io.run() in main thread within main function):**

```
main-Thread #32
printer-Thread #32
print1-Thread #32
        Timer 1: 0
print2-Thread #32
        Timer 2: 1
print1-Thread #32
        Timer 1: 2
print2-Thread #32
        Timer 2: 3
print1-Thread #32
        Timer 1: 4
print2-Thread #32
        Timer 2: 5
print1-Thread #32
        Timer 1: 6
print2-Thread #32
        Timer 2: 7
print1-Thread #32
        Timer 1: 8
print2-Thread #32
        Timer 2: 9
~printer-Thread #32
        Final count is 10
```

Observation1: both `print1` and `print2` are called by main-thread.

**Test 2 (NOT call io.run() in main thread within main function):**

```
main-Thread #40
printer-Thread #40
print1-Thread #29
        Timer 1: 0
print2-Thread #29
        Timer 2: 1
print1-Thread #29
        Timer 1: 2
print2-Thread #29
        Timer 2: 3
print1-Thread #29
        Timer 1: 4
print2-Thread #29
        Timer 2: 5
print1-Thread #29
        Timer 1: 6
print2-Thread #29
        Timer 2: 7
print1-Thread #29
        Timer 1: 8
print2-Thread #29
        Timer 2: 9
~printer-Thread #40
        Final count is 10
```

Observation2: Neither `print1` and `print2` are called by main-thread.

Note: the testing results are come from my local linux box(g++ (Ubuntu 11.1.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 11.1.0)). The result looks a little different from coliru.

> In that case io_context operates like a classic thread pool.
> Asynchronous tasks are performed somewhere on the OS side, however
> completion handlers are invoked on those threads where io_context::run
> function is running. To be more precise: every completion handler is
> invoked on a first free thread which io_context::run function is
> running on.

**Question**> what is the main reason that we want to call `io.run);` in both main and a new thread in the original tutorial?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of it is required. It merely shows that tasks are distributed over all thread participating in running/polling the execution context.

In that sense, the code as written is simply the cheapest way to get 2 threads  running the io context. In a more recent Boost version, one could argue that `thread_pool` is cleaner code, but results in 3 threads (counting the main thread):

```
int main()
{
    report("main") << std::endl;
    boost::asio::thread_pool io(2);

    printer p(io.get_executor());
    io.join();
}
```

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/24b3ef4ae7a25cb5)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind/bind.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
namespace asio = boost::asio;

std::ostream& report(const std::string& suffix_msg)
{
    auto tid = std::hash<std::thread::id>{}(std::this_thread::get_id()) % 100;
    return std::cout << suffix_msg << "-Thread #" << std::setw(2)
                     << std::setfill('0') << tid;
}

class printer {
  public:
    printer(asio::any_io_executor ex)
        : strand_(asio::make_strand(ex))
        , count_(0)
    {
        report("printer") << std::endl;
        timer1_.async_wait(
            std::bind(&printer::print_callback, this, "Timer 1", std::ref(timer1_)));
        timer2_.async_wait(
            std::bind(&printer::print_callback, this, "Timer 2", std::ref(timer2_)));
    }

    ~printer()
    {
        report("~printer") << "\tFinal count is " << count_ << std::endl;
    }

    void print_callback(std::string_view name, asio::steady_timer& timer)
    {
        if (count_ < 10) {
            report("print_callback") << "\t" << name << ": " << count_ << std::endl;
            ++count_;

            timer.expires_at(timer.expiry() + asio::chrono::seconds(1));
            timer.async_wait(std::bind(&printer::print_callback, this, name,
                                       std::ref(timer)));
        }
    }

  private:
    asio::any_io_executor strand_;
    int                   count_ = 0;
    asio::steady_timer    timer1_{strand_, asio::chrono::seconds(1)};
    asio::steady_timer    timer2_{strand_, asio::chrono::seconds(1)};
};

int main()
{
    report("main") << std::endl;
    boost::asio::thread_pool io(2);

    printer p(io.get_executor());
    io.join();
}
```

Prints e.g.

```
main-Thread #59
printer-Thread #59
print_callback-Thread #06   Timer 1: 0
print_callback-Thread #06   Timer 2: 1
print_callback-Thread #74   Timer 1: 2
print_callback-Thread #74   Timer 2: 3
print_callback-Thread #74   Timer 1: 4
print_callback-Thread #74   Timer 2: 5
print_callback-Thread #74   Timer 1: 6
print_callback-Thread #74   Timer 2: 7
print_callback-Thread #74   Timer 1: 8
print_callback-Thread #74   Timer 2: 9
~printer-Thread #59 Final count is 10
```

Comment: Removing the `(2)` gets you the default number of threads: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8fb56772bb1bae60

Comment: Off topic refactoring (I can't help myself) [less repeated code](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f7f13ae19b20c7e3) or even [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/270ac9fef8447c4a) which makes it a lot clearer that the sample is about sharing state (`shared_count_`) from multiple async chains - something that becomes interesting in multithreaded environments only.